# How to place an ui button between two labels programmatically Swift

Tags: swift, scroll, uibutton

I have a simple scroll view, and I have 6 labels. I have `UIButton` which is hidden by default. My question is how can I place that `UIButton` between the first and the second labels? When this button appears (`button.isHidden = false`) other labels should move down. The height of the scroll view should also change?

[image]

Comment: I would use a `UIStackView` for this job.

Comment: could you give more information abt this please?

Comment: [Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/160646/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views-2) is a good tutorial that I can suggest.

Comment: This is a pretty complex thing to ask. You should create the constraints such that all the labels and button have a vertical spacing constraint between them. Then all you would do is take ioboutlet of button height and change its constant value. That would cause the button to increase height and push other labels below it down and increase scrollview content size automatically.

Comment: Rishabh, thank you, it worked)